# Same FLT_EVAL_METHOD, different results in GCC/Clang

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, clang

The following program (adapted from [here](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/06/On-the-precise-analysis-of-C-programs-for-FLT_EVAL_METHOD-2)) is giving inconsistent results when compiled with GCC (4.8.2) and Clang (3.5.1). In particular, the GCC result does not change even when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int r1;
double ten = 10.0;

int main(int c, char **v) {
  printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD = %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
  r1 = 0.1 == (1.0 / ten);
  printf("0.1 = %a, 1.0/ten = %a\n", 0.1, 1.0 / ten);
  printf("r1=%d\n", r1);
}
```

Tests:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 t.c && ./a.out
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0
0.1 = 0x1.999999999999ap-4, 1.0/ten = 0x1.999999999999ap-4
r1=1

$ gcc -std=c99 -mfpmath=387 t.c && ./a.out
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 2
0.1 = 0x0.0000000000001p-1022, 1.0/ten = 0x0p+0
r1=1

$ clang -std=c99 t.c && ./a.out
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0
0.1 = 0x1.999999999999ap-4, 1.0/ten = 0x1.999999999999ap-4
r1=1

$ clang -std=c99 -mfpmath=387 -mno-sse t.c && ./a.out
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 2
0.1 = 0x0.07fff00000001p-1022, 1.0/ten = 0x0p+0
r1=0
```

Note that, according to [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/06/On-the-precise-analysis-of-C-programs-for-FLT_EVAL_METHOD-2), GCC 4.4.3 used to output 0 instead of 1 in the second test.

A [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063820/floating-point-arithmetic-and-machine-epsilon) indicates that a bug has been corrected in GCC 4.6, which might explain why GCC's result is different.

I would like to confirm if any of these results would be incorrect, or if some subtle evaluation steps (e.g. a new preprocessor optimization) would justify the difference between these compilers.

Comment: I have had to investigate the behavior of old GCC versions recently and someone pointed me to https://gcc.godbolt.org which was very useful. It does not have GCC 4.4.3, but it has 4.4.7.

Comment: Was `gcc -std=c99 -mpfmath=387 t.c && ./a.out` really `gcc -std=c99 -mfpmath=387 t.c && ./a.out`  (typo?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is about something that you should resolve before you go further, because it is going to make reasoning about what happens much harder otherwise:

Surely printing `0.1 = 0x0.07fff00000001p-1022` or `0.1 = 0x0.0000000000001p-1022` can only be a bug on your compilation platform caused by ABI mismatch when using `-mfpmath=387`. None of these values can be excused by excess precision.

You could try to include your own conversion-to-readable-format in the test file, so that that conversion is also compiled with `-mfpmath=387`. Or make a small stub in another file, not compiled with that option, with a minimalistic call convention:

In other file:

```
double d;
void print_double(void)
{
  printf("%a", d);
}
```

In the file compiled with `-mfpmath=387`:

```
extern double d;
d = 0.1;
print_double();
```

Comment: Indeed, compiling first the `print_double` file without `-mfpmath=387`, and then linking its `.o` to the other file solves the issue: it prints `0x1.999999999999ap-4` in both compilers, with and without the `-mfpmath=387` flag.

Comment: @CuriosGuy Note that the style that you used, obtained with inline backticks `\``, is intended for **code**. OTOH there is no recommendation for program output, so that's probably acceptable here (but do not use `\`` for emphasis).

Comment: Sir, In my program , it says cannot find FLT_EVAL_METHOD , why is that?

Comment: @CuriosGuy `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` must be defined by the header `float.h` of a C99-compliant compiler. Maybe your C compiler does not support C99?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the `printf` problem which Pascal Cuoq addressed, I think GCC is correct here: according to the C99 standard, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` should

> evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type.

So, in this case, both `0.1` and `1.0 / ten` are being evaluated to an extended precision approximation of 1/10.

I'm not sure what Clang is doing, though [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17663780/392585) might provide some help.