# Nonintuitive result of the assignment of a double precision number to an int variable in C

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Could someone give me an explanation why I get two different 
numbers, resp. 14 and 15, as an output from the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()
{
    double Vmax = 2.9; 
    double Vmin = 1.4; 
    double step = 0.1; 

    double a =(Vmax-Vmin)/step;
    int b = (Vmax-Vmin)/step;
    int c = a;

    printf("%d  %d",b,c);  // 14 15, why?
    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get 15 in both cases but it seems I'm missing some fundamentals of the language.

I am not sure if it's relevant but I was doing the test in CodeBlocks. However, if I type the same lines of code in some on-line compiler ( [this one for example](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)) I get an answer of 15 for the two printed variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same FLT\_EVAL\_METHOD, different results in GCC/Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851350/same-flt-eval-method-different-results-in-gcc-clang)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Same FLT_EVAL_METHOD, different results in GCC/Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851350/same-flt-eval-method-different-results-in-gcc-clang), because the answers to that question don't apply to this one.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> ... why I get two different numbers ...

Aside from the usual float-point issues, the computation paths to `b` and `c` are arrived in different ways.   `c` is calculated by first saving the value as `double a`.

```
double a =(Vmax-Vmin)/step;
int b = (Vmax-Vmin)/step;
int c = a;
```

---

C allows intermediate floating-point math to be computed using wider types.  Check the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` from `<float.h>`.

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), ...
>
> -1 indeterminable;
>
> 0 evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the
>   type;
>
> 1 evaluate operations and constants of type `float` and `double` to the
>   range and precision of the `double` type, evaluate `long double`
>   operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double`
>   type;
>
> 2 evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the
>   `long double` type.
>
> C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9

OP [reported 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012793/nonintuitive-result-of-the-assignment-of-a-double-precision-number-to-an-int-var/49013979#comment85032564_49012793)

By saving the quotient in `double a = (Vmax-Vmin)/step;`, precision is forced to `double` whereas `int b = (Vmax-Vmin)/step;` could compute as `long double`.

This subtle difference results from `(Vmax-Vmin)/step` (computed perhaps as `long double`) being saved as a `double` versus remaining a `long double`. One as 15 (or just above), and the other just under 15.  `int` truncation amplifies this difference to 15 and 14.

On another compiler, the results may both have been the same due to `FLT_EVAL_METHOD < 2` or other floating-point characteristics.

---

Conversion to `int` from a floating-point number is severe with numbers near a whole number.  Often better to `round()` or `lround()`.  The best solution is situation dependent.

Comment: thank you for your assistance and explanation! Now when I tested the `FTL_EVAL_METHOD` on the online compiler, where I got "expected" answers of 15 for the tho variables, I've got a result of 0. However, the lesson is that a noob like me must be careful when doing such "simple", at first glance, computations :)

Comment: @GeorgiD With `FTL_EVAL_METHOD == 0` I'd expect the same result for both `b,c`, yet possibly not 15, but 14.  As many, including [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014051/2410359) suggest, be careful about converting FP to `int`- that applies to us all, not just learners.

Answer (score 26):

This is indeed an interesting question, here is what happens precisely in your hardware. This answer gives the exact calculations with the precision of IEEE `double` precision floats, i.e. 52 bits mantissa plus one implicit bit. For details on the representation, see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Ok, so you first define some variables:

```
double Vmax = 2.9;
double Vmin = 1.4;
double step = 0.1;
```

The respective values in binary will be

```
Vmax =    10.111001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
Vmin =    1.0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
step = .00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

If you count the bits, you will see that I have given the first bit that is set plus 52 bits to the right. This is exactly the precision at which your computer stores a `double`. **Note that the value of `step` has been rounded up.**

Now you do some math on these numbers. The first operation, the subtraction, results in the precise result:

```
 10.111001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
- 1.0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
--------------------------------------------------------
  1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Then you divide by `step`, which has been rounded up by your compiler:

```
   1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 /  .00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
--------------------------------------------------------
1110.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111
```

Due to the rounding of `step`, the result is a tad below `15`. Unlike before, I have **not** rounded immediately, because that is precisely where the interesting stuff happens: Your CPU can indeed store floating point numbers of greater precision than a `double`, so rounding does not take place immediately.

So, when you convert the result of `(Vmax-Vmin)/step` directly to an `int`, your CPU simply cuts off the bits after the fractional point (this is how the implicit `double -> int` conversion is defined by the language standards):

```
               1110.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111
cutoff to int: 1110
```

However, if you first store the result in a variable of type double, rounding takes place:

```
               1110.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111
rounded:       1111.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
cutoff to int: 1111
```

And this is precisely the result you got.

Comment: Great, every question on floating-point numbers should have concrete examples like this.

Comment: "Note that the value of step has been rounded up. This rounding is prescribed by the language standards.".  All 3 `Vmax, Vmin, step` have incurred rounding.  `step`: up.  `Vmax, Vmin`:down. these are   examples of round to nearest.  "This rounding is prescribed by the language standards."  Hmmm, review §5.2.4.2.2 6.  Instead the accuracy and rounding direction/mode is implementation defined behavior.   Various FP standards do specify round-to-nearest as the default rounding mode, but not C.  Still many platforms comply with IEEE 754 - or nearly so.

Comment: @chux Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression, that floating point **literals** have to be rounded to nearest. Rounding at other places is indeed implementation defined, like the rounding that happens when the result of the calculation is stored.

Comment: @cmaster Looks like it is still ID behavior.  §6.4.4.2 7 "The translation-time conversion of floating constants should match the execution-time
conversion of character strings by library functions, such as strtod, given matching
inputs suitable for both conversions, the same result format, and default execution-time
rounding" and footnote "The specification for the library functions recommends more accurate conversion than required for
floating constants (see 7.22.1.3)."  C is fairly loose on these matters about _floating constants_.

Comment: @chux Ok, I have removed the offending sentence.

Answer (score 22):

The "simple" answer is that those seemingly-simple numbers 2.9, 1.4, and 0.1 are all represented internally as binary floating point, and in binary, the number 1/10 is represented as the infinitely-repeating binary fraction 0.00011001100110011...[2] .  (This is analogous to the way 1/3 in decimal ends up being 0.333333333... .)  Converted back to decimal, those original numbers end up being things like 2.8999999999, 1.3999999999, and 0.0999999999.  And when you do additional math on them, those .0999999999's tend to proliferate.

And then the additional problem is that the path by which you compute something -- whether you store it in intermediate variables of a particular type, or compute it "all at once", meaning that the processor might use internal registers with greater precision than type `double` -- can end up making a significant difference.

The bottom line is that when you convert a `double` back to an `int`, you almost always want to *round*, not truncate.  What happened here was that (in effect) one computation path gave you 15.0000000001 which truncated down to 15, while the other gave you 14.999999999 which truncated all the way down to 14.

See also [question 14.4a](http://c-faq.com/fp/strangefp.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: To be precise, if 1/10 *were* represented as the infinitely-repeating binary fraction `0.00011001100110011...` (and if arithmetic were done in a mathematically correct way) then there wouldn't be a problem, but actually it's represented as that binary fraction truncated to a certain number of digits. (Just as, in decimal, the number `0.333333…` with an infinite sequence of digits is exactly 1/3, but when truncated to a finite number of digits, we get something like `0.33333333333333` which is *not* exactly 1/3.)

Answer (score 6):

An equivalent problem is analyzed in [analysis of C programs for FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2).

If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2`:

```
double a =(Vmax-Vmin)/step;
int b = (Vmax-Vmin)/step;
int c = a;
```

computes `b` by evaluating a `long double` expression then truncating it to a `int`, whereas for `c` it's evaluating from `long double`, truncating it to `double` and then to `int`.

So both values are not obtained with the same process, and this may lead to different results because floating types does not provides usual exact arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, thank you Jean-Baptiste! This is what I understood from yesterdays discussions as well after @chux mentioned about the `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.