# Why the output is different how ever the formula is the same?

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
int y = 89;
int foo =  (y / 10.0 - y / 10) * 10;
int bar = (89 / 10.0 - 89 / 10) * 10;
cout << foo << ' ' << bar << '\n';
```

The above code is intended to get the last digit of an integer y, the strange thing is that foo is `8` and bar is `9`, why this happens? What's the difference between the two versions of expressions?

Comment: This [test](https://godbolt.org/z/RSrboG) gives `9 9` Btw, why not do `y % 10` (a modulus operation) to get the last digit?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use codeblocks compiler 17.12

Comment: I'm pretty sure it supports modulus operations. Try `std::cout << y % 10 << '\n';` and you'll get the last digit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know that modulo 10 will give the intended answer, I just want to see if there's a difference between the two versions or not.

Comment: @Migo I can't see why it would be. `89/10.0 == 8.9` and `89/10 == 8`. `8.9 - 8 == 0.9` `0.9 * 10 == 9.0` and that's what's happening in both formulas. Are you saying that when you compile the test code I showed, you get `8 9` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, but in Visual Studio I get `9 9`.

Comment: I'd look at the generated assembly code and maybe submit an error report.

Comment: I get 9, 9 compiling with g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0 and also 9, 9 when using Code::Blocks 16.01 (but that also uses gnu gcc)

Comment: The only way I managed to reproduce your output is by messing up with the rounding modes, compiling without optimizations: https://godbolt.org/z/rQQQWt How have you set up your compilation?

Comment: @TarekDakhran: The fact you failed to reproduce the problem in your environment is not proof the problem does not exist.

Comment: there are lots of duplicates: [double variable not equal to double expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37626687/995714), [Apparently identical math expressions with different output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33795031/995714), [Difference in floating point arithmetics between x86 and x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710272/995714), [Difference in casting float to int, 32-bit C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54881541/995714), [Nonintuitive result of the assignment of a double precision number to an int variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012793/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apparently identical math expressions with different output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795031/apparently-identical-math-expressions-with-different-output)

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard permits an implementation to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than is required by the nominal format. For example, `float` expressions may be evaluated as if they were `double` or more, and `double` expressions may be evaluated as if they were `long double`. This extra precision can cause differences in evaluation, especially where discontinuous functions (such as conversion to `int`) are used.

For example, given `y = 89`, `y / 10.0 - y / 10` would be .9 in real-number arithmetic, but it is 0.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625 in `double` (IEEE-754 binary64) arithmetic and 0.89999999999999999965305530480463858111761510372161865234375 in `long double` (Intel’s 80-bit format) arithmetic, and then multiplying by 10 and converting to `int` produces 9 or 8, respectively.

With optimization disabled, the compiler may be evaluating the expression with `y` at run-time and the expression with `89` during compilation, and it may be using different precisions for them. With optimization, the compiler is likely to recognize `y` is effectively a constant `89` in the first expression and evaluate both expressions during compilation, use the same method for both.

The C++ standard requires that cast and assignment operations convert to the nominal type, so one test to see if this is happening is to insert casts:

```
int foo = (double) ((double) (y / 10.0) - y / 10) * 10;
int bar = (double) ((double) (89 / 10.0) - 89 / 10) * 10;
```

If this results in `foo` and `bar` being identical, that supports the hypothesis. Your compiler may have switches to control how floating-point expressions are evaluated.

Another test is to include `<cfloat>` and print the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. If it is 0, the implementation claims to evaluate floating-point operations in their nominal type, and this behavior should not occur. If it is 1 or 2, the implementation claims to use `double` or `long double` to evaluate `double` expressions, respectively, and this behavior should again not occur, since both expressions will be evaluated the same way. If it is −1, the implementation is not making these claims, and the behavior may occur.

To get the last digit of a non-negative integer, use `y % 10`.